# How to Dynamically (Runtime by AdminUser) add Role and it's Object Permission in Asp.net Core 2.x using built in Authorization?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Last year I started using asp.net core MVC.
I used to make a security system using role and permissions based like:

When the application is first deployed into production, the application creates a default admin
role and admin user. This user has full application access.

This user can create a new roles and give access permission to a new role (including creating new role and user permissions) and assign it to the new user.

[reference](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113366/Concepts/Security-System/Security-System-Overview) for this type of security system:

I read Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

And there everything is in **hardcoded string** .

How can I implement this in asp.net core2.x with EF Core for DB access?

(If possible provide some detail explanation links)

**For an Example**: Admin user Create Role 'PurchaseManager' and give access to this URL example.com/Product [Get/POST/PUT/DELETE] etc. all. after Admin user Create another Role 'StoreManager' and give access to this URL example.com/Product [Get Only]

**this process will be done in production.**

Comment: I'm not really sure what problem you are facing so it might be difficult for people to help you. Consider asking a more specific question or providing a minimal example of the problem you are facing.

Comment: @CalC did you check a reference link?

Comment: Reference link links to non-aspnetcore documentation, but your question tagged only aspnetcore, so it's unclear what do you want. What is "hardcoded string"? You want add role and user at app startup?

Comment: @Dmitry yes Reference link is for winfrom.

Comment: @Dmitry but i want to use same implimation in asp.net core using authorization. after the application is deployed in production. Admin user can create new user and their roles with new Permission which is stored in DataBase. For an Example : Admin user Create Role 'PurchaseManager' and give acess to this url http://example.com/Product/ [Get/POST/PUT/DELETE] etc. all. after  Admin user Create another Role 'StoreManager' and give acess to this url http://example.com/Product/ [Get Only]